# a string of beads VS a strand of beads

Tags: difference

Am I right that a string of beads and a strand of beads are synonyms?
If not, then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never really heard "strand of beads" being used.  "String of beads" is the usual expression, but even that is quite rare.  I'd normally just say "necklace" or "bead necklace" etc.

A "strand" is usually one line that is twisted together to make a rope.

A google search suggests nearly all uses of "string of beads" now refer to a plant that has small leaves on hanging vines. And "strand of beads" is used for bracelets and necklaces that are made from several strings of small beads twisted together.

So "string of beads" is probably a better expression to use in most cases. But you'd say "I bought my girlfriend a necklace" rather than "a string of beads".

Comment: You said "I've never really heard "strand of beads" being used". Did you hear "strand of pearls"? Or is it an unusual collocation too? Thanks.

Comment: same in both case.  "string of pearls" is okay, but "pearl necklace" seems more likely in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are synonyms, in that case.

Not in all cases, however. A string of objects can be a collection of any similar objects. A strand of objects, however, is confined to pearls and, as you say, beads, for the type of object.

In conclusion, though a string of objects is the more general term, they are synonymous in your specific use case.

Thanks to [@KateBunting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866) for pointing out the second Oxford Languages definition of the word "strand." The definitions of the word "strand" may be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+strand).

Comment: 'Strand of beads' is not part of my vocabulary, but if you google it you get pictures of strings of beads.

Comment: @KateBunting My best guess it that the Google search engine thought it was a typo for "string of beads." If you google the definition of "strand", [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+strand), it will not list any definitions as "a collection of consecutive items."

Comment: Likewise, under the Oxford definition for "string" that I alluded to ("a sequence of similar items or events"), it does not list "strand" as one of the synonyms for that particular definition.

Comment: On the [Google definition for "string"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+string), you might have to click "See more" to find the definition I referenced.

Comment: See [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sca_esv=579625040&sxsrf=AM9HkKkDqnEXYvuuoIptxvini-K8FNeUPg:1699196282381&q=strand+of+beads&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb_8G2j62CAxUEXkEAHXF-D5YQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1358&bih=620&dpr=1). See also Oxford Languages definition 2.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh. I see. I hadn't realized there was a second definition.